# Upper hemisphere of $S^n, n \geq 2$ is simply-connected

Tags: homotopy-theory, connectedness

The upper hemisphere $S^n, n \geq 2$ is simply-connected.

My idea  is the  following:

Let $H^n:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} |$ such that $||x|| = 1$ and $x_n \geq 0 \}$

By showing that $H^n$ is contractible it follows that it is simply connected (by a proposition). Let us show that $H^n$ is contractible.

**Aim**: $H^n \simeq \{x_0\}$ for $x_0 = (0,0,0, ...,1).$

**1. Show $g \circ f \simeq id_{\{x_0\}}$**

Let $g: H^n \rightarrow \{x_0\}$ with $g(x) = x_0$      $\forall x \in H^n$ and

$f:\{x_0\} \rightarrow \{x_0\} \subset H^n $ with $f(x_0) = x_0$. Note that $g$ and $f$ are continuous.

$g \circ f: \{x_0\} \to \{x_0\}, g \circ f= g(f(x)) = g(x) = x_0 \implies g \circ f \simeq id_{\{x_0\}} $

**2. Show $f \circ g  \simeq id_{H^n}$**

Define $H: H^n \times [0,1] \to H^n, H(x,t) = \frac{(1-t)x_0 + tx}{||(1-t)x_0+tx)||}$. Since we chose $x_0 = (0,0,0, ...,1)$ we made sure that we will not divide by $0$. Obviously $H(x,t) \in H^n$ since $||H(x,t)|| = 1.$ $H(x,t)$ is a composition of contin. functions $\implies H(x,t)$ is continuous.

$H(x,0) = \frac{x_0}{||x_0||} = x_0 = f\circ g$

$H(x,1) = \frac{x}{||x||}= x = id_{H^n}$

$\implies f \circ g \simeq id_{H^n}$

So we have that $H^n \simeq \{x_0\}$ i.e. $H^n $ is contractible, from that it follows that $H^n$ is simply connected.

Does that work?

Comment: What if $x=-x_0$ ? Compute $H(-x_0,1/2)$ and you will see that you do divide by zero. Also, when saying "Obviously $H(x,t)\in H^n$, you need to check that the last coordinate is greater or equal to zero (this is indeed the case but it requires a justification).

Comment: For your argument you nowhere used that you're on $H^n$ and you need that so that your denominator doesn't get zero. Also that $||H(x,t)|| = 1$ only means that $H(x,t) \in S^n$.

Comment: @Roland was faster. But I agree with his points.

Comment: With the edit, you indeed don't divide by zero and the homotopy is fine. As @MaikPickl and I suggest, prove in more details that you don't divide by zero and that $H(x,t)\in H^n$ (don't forget the part where the last coordinate must be greater or equal to zero).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not sure how to prove that I don't divide by zero. But I imagine it in that way, that I pick any point in $H^n$ and then I'm "drawing" a line between $x_0$ and $x \in H^n$ and by dividing with its norm I get that it "lands" on $H^n \subset S^n$. Since dividing a vector by its norm equals always 1?

Comment: Not to be captain obvious, but intuitively this is perfectly trivial, since we clearly have the homeomorphism type of a disk, which is clearly contractible.  I understand you need to make this precise though.

Comment: @alex123 Hey Alex, to check that your denominator isn't zero you have to check that  $||(1-t)x_0+tx|| \neq 0$, which is the case if $(1-t)x_0+tx$ isn't the zero vector. If you wan't to be very rigorous you should show this by calculation. You could for example show that the only way that $(1-t)x_0+tx$ is the zero vector is when $x=-x_0$ but $-x_0 \notin H_n$.  Secondly to show that $H(x,t)$ is on $H_n$ you need to make a argument, that the last coordinate is positive.

Comment: @alex1232 Just to add: your argument, that your drawing the line from $x_0$ to $x$ is indeed right. But these appeals to visualizations only work very well in low dimensions. What about the Hemisphere in 10 dimensions? Is it still obvious whats going on there? I would say only if you have a rigorous argument you can fall back to.

Comment: @MaikPickl Great! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @alex1232 You're very welcome. Just to add: these are minor points you have to look out for. Overall your argument is very well done!